# InnerHtml string to excel as table in multiple sheets ASP.Net

Tags: c#

Am having two string variables containing innerHTML code,two sheets has to be created in single excel and two tables has to be placed in two sheets. While Exporting to excel, it is writing the innerHTML instead of creating as formatted HTML table. Please help us how to convert innerHTML variable as table format in excel.

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried?

Comment: string HTMLstr = "<table><tr align=center><td colspan=9><b><font size=4 face=Calibri>SALES SUMMARY</font></b></td></tr>        
  <TABLE  border=1 class=gridtable><TR><TD>Customer Name:</TD><TD>TEST</TD></TR><tr><td></td></tr> 
 </TR></TABLE> "
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsapp = null;
        Workbook xlsbook = null;
        Worksheet xlsdoc1 = null;
        Worksheet xlsdoc2 = null;
        xlsapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Comment: xlsbook = xlsapp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        xlsdoc2 = (Worksheet)xlsbook.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value);
        xlsdoc1 = (Worksheet)xlsbook.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value);
        xlsdoc1.Name = "Job Summary";
        xlsdoc2.Name = "Job Details";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
         range = xlsdoc1.Range["A2", "K2"];
            range.Merge();
            range.Value2 = "Job Summary";
            range.Font.Name = "Bookman Old Style";

Comment: range.Font.Size = 14;
            range.Font.ColorIndex = 5;
            range.Font.Bold = true;
            range.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            range.BorderAround(XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, XlBorderWeight.xlThin, XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexNone, XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexNone);

Comment: //First Sheet
            {
                range = xlsdoc1.Range["A4", "A4"];
                range.Value2 = "Job Id:";
                range = xlsdoc1.Range["B4", "B4"];
                range.Value2 =  HTMLstr;
                range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
                range.Font.Bold = true;
            }

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = xlsapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, Constants.xlSolid, false,
            false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            
        }
         when I give range.Value2 =  HTMLstr; it is displaying in excel as innerHTML Value